What are the ways to estimate treatment effects for staggered treatment? (DID)
I have a setting where firms receiving treatments in a staggered manner. I would like to identify the treatment effect, and I can think of several ways but do not know which is suitable.

matching x DID (transforming the treatment year to t=0): The OLS looks like Y_i,t = Treat_i + Post_t + Treat_i * Post_t

matching x DID (without transforming the treatment year to t=0): The OLS looks like Y_i,t = Treat_i + Post_i,t + Treat_i * Post_i,t


Recently staggered DID has been popular, but before considering using staggered DID(TWFE, stacked DID, Callaway and Sant'Anna, and etc.), I would like to know about these two methods, the pros and cons.
Thanks in advance!
I think method 1 is making a 2x2 DID and so it is easy to interpret. But it disregards the difference of treatment timing, but I do not know how this affect the result.
Method 2 takes into account the difference in treatment timing, but now it is not a simple 2x2 DID. Should I understand that it will return treatment effect for each treatment period? If so, what is it comparing, is it units treated in a specific year with units never treated, or units treated in a specific year with units not treated in that year?
